# Configure mod_mono to deploy a wcf service (CentOS)

Tags: wcf, centos, mod-mono

I have been asked to deploy WCF service to `mod_mono` at `CentOS` and i am sequentially using given below **STEPS** to install `mono` and `mod_mono`.

Every things installs well ,but i can not find `/usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_mono.so` (which i come to know is a important file to set up mod_mono server ).

Can anyone please tell me what wrong i am doing.

P.S: I am new to linux so please excuse if it is a silly question.

**STEPS:**

```
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-2.10.2.tar.bz2

wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mod_mono/mod_mono-2.10.tar.bz2
cd /mono-2.10.2
 ./configure  --prefix=/opt/mono 
 make ; make install
cd ../mod_mono-2.10
./configure --prefix=/opt/mono --with-mono-prefix=/opt/mono
make ; make install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run by downgrading mySql version.